# Does H2 support a collation defintion for one single column?

Tags: mysql, sql, h2, collation, ddl

I want to make a single H2 column in a H2 database to have a other collation (case insensitive) then the other columns (that are case sensitive).

In MySQL I would do this:

```
ALTER TABLE users MODIFY login VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

Is there a similar feature in H2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

H2 only supports one collation per database (via [`SET COLLATION`](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#set_collation) statement).

What it does support is a case-insensitive data type, [`VARCHAR_IGNORECASE`](http://h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#varchar_ignorecase_type). Internally, this data type is using [`String.compareToIgnoreCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29). This may or may not work for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

From [H2 reference guide](http://h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#varchar_ignorecase_type):

```
ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN login VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(255)
```