# perform case insensitive string search in H2?

Tags: sql, h2, case-sensitive

I'm using H2 to run some database code that was originally designed to be used with MySQL, and has some queries that need to match data in a case-insensitive manner.  I've found the "IGNORECASE=TRUE" option in the JDBC connection URL, which has helped in some cases, but it doesn't seem to work everywhere.  For example, in MySQL I have the following (simplified) query:

```
select e.id from entities e left join ranges r on e.range=r.id
 where locate (?, e.name) between r.start and r.end
```

Unfortunately this isn't working in H2 because it's performing the match as case sensitive, by I need it to be insensitive.

Is there some option to H2 to change the behaviour of functions like locate to be case sensitive?  Or another function that will do the same job?  Would running `locate (?, lcase(e.name))` with the input parameter also changed to lower case be suitable, or would it be inefficient or fail on obscure corner cases?

*EDIT* @AndrewMortan suggested a link to a question with answers to a related question in the comments.  I've tried both suggestions (using a SET COLLATION command prior to creating tables to set a default collation and using the 'VARCHAR_IGNORECASE' datatype in fields that need to have case insensitive comparisons, unforunately neither has worked:

```
create schema test;
set schema test;
set collation en strength primary;
create table test ( t varchar_ignorecase(255) not null );
insert into test(t) values ('THIS SHOULD BE FINDABLE WITH A LOWER CASE SEARCH STRING');
select t, locate('should', t) from test;
```

produces the results:

```
T                                    LOCATE('should', T)  
THIS SHOULD BE FINDABLE WITH A ...   0
```

whereas:

```
select t, locate('SHOULD', t) from test;
```

gives:

```
T                                    LOCATE('SHOULD', T)  
THIS SHOULD BE FINDABLE WITH A ...   6
```

Comment: Perhaps the answers to [Does H2 support a collation defintion for one single column?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21884157/1115360) will help.

Comment: @AndrewMorton ... Perhaps, yes. It looks like the VARCHAR_IGNORECASE type could work. Will have to check

Comment: @AndrewMorton - unfortunately not, no.  It seems that `locate` ignores both of these settings, as well as ignoring the `IGNORECASE=TRUE` setting in the connection URL.

Comment: I see [h2database - issue #591 INSTR behaves case sensitive on VARCHAR_IGNORECASE column](https://code.google.com/archive/p/h2database/issues/591) is marked as "WontFix". Perhaps you could look through the other [H2 issues](https://code.google.com/archive/p/h2database/issues) to see if `locate` has been noted to have the same behaviour.

Comment: It could be that H2 is a sub-optimal choice for the database, and almost any other RDBMS (including MySQL) would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try adding the `lower()` function?

```
select e.id from entities e left join ranges r on e.range=r.id
  where locate (lower(?), lower(e.name)) between r.start and r.end
```

That should work, or am I wrong?

If you are running this query on many rows very often you could create a virtual column as in:

```
alter table element add (
  name_lower varchar(100) as lower(name)
);
```

So your query would be faster:

```
select e.id from entities e left join ranges r on e.range=r.id
  where locate (lower(?), e.name_lower) between r.start and r.end
```

What the heck, you can even index by the virtual column:

```
create index ix_element_add_low on element (address_lower);
```

if you think that it can make it faster.

Comment: It's not a subject I know a lot about, but my understanding is that some unicode strings cannot be compared correctly by forcing them to either upper or lower case, because there are characters that may convert to multiple different variants on case conversion. https://eev.ee/blog/2015/09/12/dark-corners-of-unicode/ gives an example of "ı" which is the correct lower-case equivalent of "I" in Turkish, while "i" is the correct lower-casing in other languages -- a correct solution to this problem should be able to determine that "ı" and "I" are equivalent, but this doesn't, I think